# Exercise 4.3 - Chapter 2 - Algebraic Topology by William S. Massey

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

I didn't understand why is requisited in the below question. I'm not very good with English, then I believe my doubt is is due to lack of understanding of the statement. Can anyone write in mathematics terms what is requisited in the below question? Thanks in advance!

> $\textbf{4.3}$ Prove that, if $A$ is a retract of $X$, $r: X \longrightarrow A$ ia a retraction, $i: A \longrightarrow X$ is the inclusion and $i_* \pi_1(A)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$, then $\pi_1(X)$ is the direct product of the subgroups image $i_*$ and kernel $r_*$.
>
> $\textbf{EDIT:}$
>
> I tried to solve the problem now I know what I need to prove, but I'm stuck can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!
>
> My attempt:
>
> First, observe that $r \circ i$ is the identity map of $A$ which forces that $r_*$ is epimorphism and $i_*$ is monomorphism. Since $i_*$ is a monomorphism, $ker \ i_* = \{ e \}$ and by Isomorphism Theorem of Groups, we have $\pi_1(A)/ \{ e \} = \pi_1(A)/ker \ i_* \cong i_* \left( \pi_1(A) \right)$ and, because there is a natural isomorphism between $\pi_1(A)$ and $\pi_1(A)/ \{ e \}$, we have
>
> $$\pi_1(A) \cong \pi_1(A)/ \{ e \} = \pi_1(A)/ker \ i_* \cong i_* \left( \pi_1(A) \right) \hspace{5cm} (1)$$
>
> Now, we have, by the fact $r_*$ is an epimorphism and by the Isomorphism Theorem of Groups, that
>
> $$\pi_1(X)/ ker \ k_* \cong \pi_1(A) \hspace{10cm} (2)$$
>
> $(1)$ and $(2)$ allow us state that

$$\pi_1(X)/ ker \ k_* \cong i_* \left( \pi_1(A) \right) \hspace{9cm} (3)$$

> As $\pi_1(X) = \bigcup_{f \in \pi_1(X)} f \ ker \ k_*$ and by $(3)$, every $g \in \pi_1(X)$ can be written like $g = f \cdot n$ and $g = h$, where $f \in \pi_1(X)$, $n \in \ ker \ k_*$, $\cdot$ represent the operation of link paths and $h \in i_* \left( \pi_1(A) \right)$, then
>
> $$h = g = f \cdot n \Longrightarrow h = f \cdot n \Longrightarrow f = h \cdot n^{-1}$$
>
> Since $f = h \cdot n^{-1}$ and $f \in \pi_1(X)$, we can construct an isomorphism $j: Dom (j) \subset \pi_1(X) \longrightarrow i_* \left( \pi_1(A) \right) \times ker \ k_*$ such that $h \cdot n^{-1} \mapsto (h, n^{-1})$. Remains to show that $Dom (j) = \pi_1(X)$

Comment: If $A$ is a retract of $X$ and $i_*\pi_1(A)\triangleleft \pi_1(X)$, show that $\pi_1(X)\cong\operatorname{im} i_*\times\ker r_*$. Does that help?

Comment: I thought it could be this, but I didn't sure if I had translated right. This helps me, thanks!